# Google Script HtmlService, Get Passed URL Variable Replicating with Multiple Tabs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created a web app that can accept variables in the URL string, however when I open several tabs with different values for the `cID` whichever tab is opened last reflects across all tabs. It is a strange phenomenon and I was hoping someone would be able to help me solve why it is happening and possibly present a solution to avoid it.

The server side creation of the HTML page:

```
function doGet(e) {
   var id = e.parameter.cID

    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('id',id);

    return HtmlService
           .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
           .evaluate()
           .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

The function that calls once the page loads:

```
function idLock() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getID).returnID();
}
```

The server side function that gets the information based on the passed in `cID`:

```
function returnID(){
   return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('id');
}
```

My best guess is that the `id` variable is some how global as apposed to instance based. If this is the case, how do I prevent that?

Comment: When you state "tabs", you mean browser tabs.  Not tabs inside of your HTML.  So you open a Web App in one tab, then open a Web App in another tab with a different "id", and then the Web App in the first browser tab automatically gets updated with the last "id"?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean browser tabs. For example if I open example.com?cID=1234 and example.com?cID=5678 both pages will show 5678 if I open them before the first page completely loads. If that makes sense.

Comment: The second value is getting written to Properties Service before the first value is being retrieved in the first browser tab.  The first thing you should do is use Lock Service, and see if that solves the problem.  [Apps Script Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service)  Lock Service "should" fix your problem **IF** your `doGet()` function isn't calling any other function.  If Lock Service doesn't solve the problem, then it gets more complicated.

Comment: Thank you Sandy, that is very interesting. I need to take some time and learn how to use Script Lock Service. Do you know of any other way to store a variable like this other than Properties Service? It seems far more complicated than a standard website would be due to is being an application.

Comment: If you want persistent storage, Properties Service is the only alternative, other than writing data to a file somewhere.  Cache Service can be used to store values that delete themselves after a given time.  The default is something like 10 minutes?  Cache Service might be an option if you don't need to store the value for any longer than a few minutes, and it might be faster than Properties Service.

Comment: All I am looking for is taking the `cID` value from the URL and passing that value to the pages JavaScript. Usually this will happen when a link is triggered, however it becomes awkward using HTMLService with Google Script as the `window.location` options brings up an entirely different URL. Since I can't pull the string value from the URL directly, I have to find a way of passing it on page load which has become problematic.

Comment: In that case I would use Cache Service and a Script Lock.

Comment: I was able to pass this value instance based. I will look into ScriptLock and  Cache Service! Did not know they existed before. Thank you again Sandy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I was able to pass this information was by making a variable that was global as far as the page instance was concerned, but not global in the sense of `PropertyServices`.

```
var myPar;

function doGet(e) {
   myPar = e.parameter.cID

   return HtmlService
       .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
       .evaluate()
       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

How I was able to pass this into the HTML was by adding `<?= myPar ?>`

This may not be the best way, but it did return the results I was hoping for.

Comment: This is great! I like it.

Comment: Thank you Sandy, and thanks for helping me figure it out! It is going to be very useful.